# Adding Advance Custom Field field in Genesis Child Theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress

What can I do in order to add an ACF textarea into a Genesis child theme template.

I want to disply ACF textarea Fileds in to Page or Post whereever i want. please help me

I found this code.

```
add_action('genesis_header', 'add_content_to_header');

function add_content_to_header() {
    echo get_field('my_textarea_field');';
}
```

Or do put it directly into a child theme template file, just put this whereever you want:

```
the_field('my_textarea_field');
```

Using this code site broken.

Comment: if you add `<?php the_field('my_textarea_field'); ?>` in all of your theme template files it should work. Take a screen shot of broken page or tell the error which you get to help better, !!!!!!Remember this name `my_textarea_field` shoud exactly the same as `Field Name` in ACF.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the changes in your Child theme (not the Parent).

First, you need to discover which PHP file needs the ACF hooks added to it. Posts and Pages use different files, so if you want the field to display in both, you will need to edit both PHP files. Typically, "content.php" is for Posts. To test if it's the right file, make a copy of "content.php" and put it in your Child theme folder, then look at the PHP file and determine where your hook needs to go. I just add "Hello" in between the PHP functions and hit SAVE & refresh my page to see if it's the right place.

Once you find the right file and location in the code, you should add a conditional statement to display your field. This way, WP will only display the field if you have added content.

```
<?php
if(get_field('field_name'))
{
    echo '<p>' . get_field('field_name') . '</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: This code displays table in a page but i want to display acf fields whereever in a page. i placed this code in functions.php       '//* Display custom fields
add_action( 'genesis_after_entry_content', 'my_custom_field' );
function my_custom_field () {
 echo '<div class="my_custom_field">';
 the_field('my_custom_field');
 echo '</div>';
}'

Comment: @raja , I am not sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to get the field to display in the WordPress page/post editor? Or do you already know how to do that and are now trying to get the information from that field to display on the rendered page?

Comment: i want to display acf fields whereever i want in page or post with shortcut code to be placed.